# Need IEDriver option/capability for protractor config file to use tabs instead of windows for popups.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

IEDriver opens new pop-ups in a new window.  Is there an IE option/capability I can include in my protractor conf.js file to force it to open the popups in a tab instead?  My web application in non-angular.

Comment: Just switch to the newly opened window. Why would you want to alter the behavior? Users won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There is no option for this behavior.